# What is Drift flux in two phase flow (Fluid Mechanics)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering, multiphase-flow

I recently started learning about two phase flows. While studying I came across relative velocity, drift velocity and drift flux. I understand the first two terms, but I don't understand the concept of drift flux. It is easy to understand the mathematics, but I don't get its significance. Can anyone explain with example.
Thank You